# Memory of disk assigned as swap doest fit

Tags: partitioning, centos-7, swap

I have problem with understanding of disk partitions for swap. Problem is about size. I create new particion via fstab with size 2GB:

```
Command (m for help): n

Partition type: p primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free) e extended Select (default p):

Using default response p

Partition number (1-4, default 1):

First sector (2048-536870911, default 2048):

Using default value 2048 Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-536870911, default 536870911): +2G Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 2 GiB is set
```

After assight it for swap

```
mkswap /dev/sdc1
swapon /dev/sdc1
```

In /etc/fstab where this uuid is for /dev/sdc1

```
UUID=1ec60ea1-1ebe-420e-9bbc-bc75f25b4cb2 none swap sw 0 0
```

After check swap size

```
>> free | gr

ep -i swap | awk '{print $2" / 1024 " }' | bc -l

2047.99609375000000000000

>> free -g

total used free shared buff/cache available 
Mem: 15 0 15 0 0 15 
Swap: 1 0 1

>> free -h

total used free shared buff/cache available

Mem: 15G 221M 15G 8.4M 299M 15G

Swap: 2.0G 0B 2.0G
```

Question is why kb outputs are not fit into 2GB and where i lost missing this memory (if i am calculating correctly i miss 4kb, is it reserved for folders hierary?) Or where i did mistake ?

Environment:

```
 >> fdisk -v
```

fdisk from util-linux 2.23.2

```
>> free -V

free from procps-ng 3.3.10

>> cat /proc/swaps | awk '{print $3" / 1024 " }' | bc -l

2047.99609375000000000000

>> cat /etc/*-release

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

NAME="CentOS Linux"

VERSION="7 (Core)"

ID="centos"

ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"

VERSION_ID="7"

PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

ANSI_COLOR="0;31"

CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"

HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

I expect same size in KB and GB same as size of created partition

Comment: @K7AAY: That page says "Swap space can be a dedicated swap partition (recommended)"...

Comment: And, the CentOS 7 in use in this case has an older kernel, so a swap partition _is_ recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (if i am calculating correctly i miss 4kb, is it reserved for folders hierary?)

Swap areas are not filesystems and do not contain a file hierarchy. They do, however, contain a 4 kB "swap header" – this is what you're creating whenever you run `mkswap`.

The [swap area header](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html) holds the UUID; number of usable pages; "bad blocks" list; and other information (such as whether the area is currently used to hold a hibernation image).