# How to calculate fdisk values

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I am try to continue understand swap on own partition. Same scenario as on [older question](https://superuser.com/questions/1499394/memory-of-disk-assigned-as-swap-doest-fit)

I want to know how to calculate correct number for fdisk command to prepare exactly 2 GB swap area. I hit correct param but i dont undestand how to generaly calculate it.

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): 
Using default response p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-536870911, default 2048): 
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-536870911, default 536870911): 4196366
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 2 GiB is set
```

Now with param 4196366 swap size is exactly 2 GB

```
>>free | grep -i swap | awk '{print "scale=2; "$2" / 1024 / 1024" }' | bc -l
2.00
```

Question is how to calculate 4196366. I was thinking like that:

```
4196366 = 2 * 2 * 1024^2 + 2 * 1024 + 14
```

So 2*1024 is probably to skip first sector
But why i need 2GB multiply by 2 again and what is magic constant 14 ? How i can generaly calculate what should be pass as argument to fdisk?

Comment: No idea about 14, but for the 2GiB part, it's actually `2 * 1024^3 / 512`, with 512 (bytes) being the logical sector/block size. (1024^1 = KiB, 1024^2 = MiB, 1024^3 = GiB). Same goes for the "1MiB alignment", it's `2048 * 512 = 1024^2 = MiB`.

Comment: Yeah you right about ^3 make sense but what can be 14?

Comment: By same way of thinking you can say 14*512/1024=7 can be swap header size

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why this answare was removed so i will paste it back:

The input is in sectors, and most disks work either with 512-byte or 4096-byte logical sectors. (512 is the traditional size, and is still emulated by many 4K disks too.) Fdisk will tell you the disk's logical sector size on startup.

In other words, you need to multiply by 2 because one sector is 512 bytes, just half of a kilobyte.

So if you want 2 gigabytes of swap, plus X kilobytes for the swap header, it's easiest to first convert both to bytes, then divide the sum by sector size (512 or 4096) to get the number of sectors:

```
swap_bytes = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
hdr_bytes = X * 1024

sector_size = 512
part_sectors = (swap_bytes + hdr_bytes) / sector_size
```

(Round up.)

Useful tools:

```
$ echo 2G | numfmt --from=si
2000000000

$ echo 2G | numfmt --from=iec
2147483648
```